# Vertex of the Intersection of Nonempty Convex Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

If $x̂ ∈ R^n$ is a vertex of $C_1 ∩ C_2$, where $C_1∈R^n$ and $C_2∈R^n$ are nonempty convex sets, then $x̂$ is either a vertex of $C_1$ or a vertex of $C_2$.

Is this a claim valid? Is there any way we can prove/disprove this claim numerically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

This image should convince you that this is untrue for $n \ge 2$. The result is true for $n=1$ though.

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks! In the question however it states that we can't prove this by drawing. Is there a way to go about the proof numerically?

Comment: Just define the rectangles using coordinates, find the intersection which is also a rectangle. And prove that the point $A$ is a vertex of the intersection rectangle while it is not a vertex of the initial rectangles.

Comment: In the question we have that $C_1∈R^n$ and $C_2∈R^n$, would this method still work for any space other than $n=2$ ?

Comment: Those two rectangles could lie in $\mathbb R^n$ with $n \ge 2$. For $n=1$ the result is true though.

Answer (score 0):

For $n \ge 2$, the intersection of the closed balls $B_i$ ($i =1,2$) with radii equal to one and centers equal to $((-1)^i, 0, \dots, 0)$ is a single point: the origin. A point is a convex set with a vertex: itself. However the two balls are convex but don't have extreme points.